# Wordpress Multisite and Subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, multisite

This sounds so noob. But I'm really new to wordpress. :)

If I create a multisite then create a new site under it, does wordpress automatically create the files? or will I be the one to install wordpress into its subdirectory?

Comment: The subdirectory is a virtual one - your server config (often via `.htaccess`) points all not-found requests to WordPress, which handles it from there.

Comment: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite/ this tutorial may be helpful for you to know about multisite in wordpress

Comment: What I did was add a new site under network admin then create the subdirectory inside the root. If I don't create the subdirectory, it shows a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to  install one copy of WordPress normally first, but it only needs that single copy of all the core files – `/wp-admin/`, `/wp-includes/`, `/wp-content/` etc. - to run all of the sites.

To add a new site, you just use the Network Admin menu and it puts any site-specific files for each **additional** site (other than your first one, that is) in numbered subdirectories.

E.g. media Library files, end up in subdirectories of `/wp-content/uploads/sites/`.

If you haven't already setup multisite, you need this line in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

Further reading:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration

Opinion: I wouldn't recommend multisite for a complete beginner – things can get really confusing even for experienced users.  The WordPress install process is very straightforward so if you have good hosting you shouldn't have trouble running separate, individual sites on the same server.

Comment: Thanks for the response @williamt. So basically all I have to do is add a new site under the network admin menu and that's it?

Comment: What I did was add a new site under network admin then create the subdirectory inside the root. If I don't create the subdirectory, it shows a 404 not found error.